# HtmlAgilityPack add new element and copy all inline css attributes to the new one

Tags: html-agility-pack

Is there a way to copy inline css attributes from one node to a new node that i will add in HtmlAgilityPack ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you can't just assign one HtmlAttributeCollection to another, but you can copy them one by one like this:

```
   foreach (HtmlAttribute attr in oldNode.Attributes)
       newNode.Attributes.Add(attr);
```